# Affectiva affdex does not process videos correctly

Tags: c++, ubuntu, affdex-sdk

I'm using affectiva affdex with C++ on Ubuntu 16.04. The programm I'm using is below. As input I'm providing a 30 min mp4 video. I have followed all steps on the affectiva webpage (downloading Ubuntu-16.04 x86_64 4.0-75 and `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev uuid-dev`).

The problem is that for some videos the processing terminates after around 2 minutes. For other videos there are large parts missing (i.e. for example 10 minutes of frames missing). I'm not getting any error and the output on the console is "[Affectiva] Video processing finised."

Why does this happen?

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
#include "VideoDetector.h"
#include "FrameDetector.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable conditional_variable;
bool processed = false;

class Listener : public affdex::ImageListener {
public:
    Listener(std::ofstream * fout) {
        this->fout = fout;
  }
  virtual void onImageCapture(affdex::Frame image){
  }
  virtual void onImageResults(std::map<affdex::FaceId, affdex::Face> faces, affdex::Frame image){
      for(auto& kv : faces){
        (*this->fout) << image.getTimestamp() << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.first << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.joy << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.fear << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.disgust << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.sadness << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.anger << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.surprise << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.contempt << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.valence << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.emotions.engagement << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.measurements.orientation.pitch << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.measurements.orientation.yaw << ",";
        (*this->fout) << kv.second.measurements.orientation.roll << std::endl;
      }
  }
private:
    std::ofstream * fout;
};

class ProcessListener : public affdex::ProcessStatusListener{
public:
    virtual void onProcessingException (affdex::AffdexException ex){
        std::cerr << "[Error] " << ex.getExceptionMessage();
    }
    virtual void onProcessingFinished (){
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
            processed = true;
            std::cout << "[Affectiva] Video processing finised." << std::endl;
        }
        conditional_variable.notify_one();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argsv)
{
        affdex::VideoDetector detector(60);
        std::string classifierPath="/home/test/affdex-sdk/data";
        detector.setClassifierPath(classifierPath);
        detector.setDetectAllEmotions(true);

        std::ofstream fout(argsv[2]);
        fout << "timestamp" << ",";
        fout << "faceId" << ",";
        fout << "joy" << ",";
        fout << "fear" << ",";
        fout << "disgust" << ",";
        fout << "sadness" << ",";
        fout << "anger" << ",";
        fout << "surprise" << ",";
        fout << "contempt" << ",";
        fout << "valence" << ",";
        fout << "engagement"  << ",";
        fout << "pitch" << ",";
        fout << "yaw" << ",";
        fout << "roll" << std::endl;

        Listener l(&fout);
        ProcessListener pl;
        detector.setImageListener(&l);
        detector.setProcessStatusListener(&pl);

        detector.start();
        detector.process(argsv[1]);
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
            conditional_variable.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
        }
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
}
```